# SHA-1 key generation ... Access Denied

Tags: java, android, google-api

I am having problems generating the SHA-1 key needed to register into the google API... This is the closest that I have come to, by entering:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\Rakeeb\.android\debug.keystore".keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Which gives an error of `Access Denied`

Other formats lead to error Invalid format.

Comment: Is the additional `.keystore` intended?

Answer (score 1):

**Easiest ways ever:**

### Update added for Android Studio V 2.2 in last step

There are two ways to do this.

**1. Faster way**:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open your Project
3. Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see **Gradle Bar**)
4. Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from **Gradle Bar**, you will see **List** Gradle scripts of your Project)
5. Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form **List** (root))
6. Click on Tasks
7. Click on Android
8. Double Click on signingReport (You will get **SHA1** and **MD5** in **Run Bar**)
9. Select **app** module from **module selection dropdown** to run or debug your application

**Check the screenshot below:**

[image]

**2. Work with Google Maps Activity**:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open Your Project
3. Click on **File** menu -> Select **New** -> Click on **Google** -> Select **Google Maps Activity**
4. A dialog would appear -> Click on **Finish**
5. Android Studio would automatically generate an **XML** file **named** with `google_maps_api.xml`
6. You would get **debug SHA1** key here (at **line number 10** of the XML file)

**Check Screenshot below:**

[image]

### Android Studio V 2.2 Update

There is an issue with **Execution**.

**Solution:**

- Click on **Toggle tasks execution/text mode** from **Run bar**

**Check Screenshot below:**

[image]

**Done.**